# Explain about convexity in geometry and in optimization.

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

My question is 'what is a difference between convexity in geometry and optimization?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In geometry, "convexity" almost always refers to convexity of sets.

In optimization, "convexity" usually refers to convexity of the objective or constraint functions.

Convexity of sets and convexity of functions are not the same thing, but they are very closely related. A function is convex if and only if the region above its graph is a convex set. Further discussion [on this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).